# IE 8 automatically renders site in IE 7 mode?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

my site was automatically being injected with  in the header when I browse using IE 8. I set my IIS with a custom header to force it to IE=8, didn't work. I set the meta tag in the header, it shows up in the source, but  was being shown before it. didn't work. What else can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but might work.

Try to add this=>

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
</head>
```

This meta tag must be first child of head element.
It will force ie8 in compability mode to work normally as ie8.

Answer (score 0):

I did tried that, didn't work.

my title

For some reason, IE8 automatically puts in the IE=7 meta tag in all my pages. is it possible that my CSS is not compatible with IE 8 so it renders in IE7 mode?

---

Thanks. i end up had to put `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` before the `<header>` tag

Comment: IE does not put a META tag in any page that doesn't have one.